# Qt:LibDash-Mpeg-Dash fatal error:QtMultimedia/qaudioformat.h: No such file or directory

Tags: cmake, qt5, mpeg-dash, qtmultimedia

I'm trying a qt project using libdash from this [link](https://github.com/bitmovin/libdash). When I try to compile,it gives me error:

> fatal error: QtMultimedia/qaudioformat.h: No such file or directory

```
#include "QtMultimedia/qaudioformat.h"
```

This project makes use of cmake.

I tried ,

**1**

```
sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev
```

**2**

```
#include "QtMultimedia/QAudioformat.h"
```

Simple `#include "QtMultimedia"` is also giving me error.

When I gave locate qt,it gave me several lines which includes;

**/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtMultimedia/qaudioformat.h**.
So it seems,the file which Im trying to access is present in the system;but it is not getting accessed;this project makes use of cmake;

Below is my cmake script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)

project(mpd)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS") 

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)


set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC")


# Find the required Qt5 libraries
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Gui)
find_package(Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5MultimediaWidgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5OpenGL)
# Find libavcodec
find_package(LibAV REQUIRED)

find_library( AVCODEC_LIBRARY libavcodec.so )

find_library( AVUTIL_LIBRARY libavutil.so )

find_library( AVFORMAT_LIBRARY libavformat.so )

find_library( AVDEVICE_LIBRARY libavdevice.so )

set(INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/local/include/")

set(LIBDASH_LIBRARIES "../build/bin/" CACHE PATH "Path to libdash.so")
set(LIBDASH_INCLUDES "../libdash/include/" CACHE PATH "Path to libdash includes")

set(INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

include_directories(${LIBDASH_INCLUDES})
link_directories(${LIBDASH_LIBRARIES})



file(GLOB qtplayer_SOURCE RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} Decoder/*.cpp libdashframework/MPD/*.cpp libdashframework/Adaptation/*.cpp libdashframework/Buffer/*.cpp libdashframework/Input/*.cpp libdashframework/Portable/*.cpp Managers/*.cpp Renderer/*.cpp UI/*.cpp UI/IDASHPlayerGuiObserver.h main.cpp)

qt5_wrap_ui(qtsampleplayer_FORMS_HEADERS qtsampleplayer.ui)
qt5_add_resources(qtsampleplayer_RESOURCES_RCC qtsampleplayer.qrc)

# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(qtsampleplayer ${qtplayer_SOURCE} ${qtsampleplayer_FORMS_HEADERS} ${qtsampleplayer_RESOURCES_RCC})

# Use the required module from Qt5.
target_link_libraries(${mpd} qtsampleplayer Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Multimedia Qt5::MultimediaWidgets Qt5::Gui Qt5::OpenGL)


# For the linker
target_link_libraries(qtsampleplayer dash ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${LIBAV_LIBRARIES} -lpthread)
```

Any suggestions/inputs will be really useful!!Thanks in advance..

Comment: `target_link_libraries(${mpd} qtsampleplayer ...)` seems off. Your target is named `qtsampleplayer`, so remove the `${mpd}`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Botje..But Im facing the same error even after removing it..